# Calculating values using begining value in column Pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Good time a day.
I have a table with data, which you can download by that link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOEuBRYEpDNz5p1m-VD5fkJS7-DmmMlwIgmibrYRWZM/edit?usp=sharing

I should calculate column "values" by defining beginner value (in table the beginner value is 1) , using formula: B2 multiple by A3, B3 multiple by A4 ... in column "values".

How i can do it in Pandas? I would bless if you can help me to do it.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) (cumulative product) method on the `Index` values, after replacing the first value by `1`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1.066373, 1.126100, 1.081077, 1.048902, 1.068631]})
df['Values'] = df.Index
df.Values[0] = 1
df.Values = df.Values.cumprod()
df
```

```
    Index       Values
0   1.066373    1.000000
1   1.126100    1.126100
2   1.081077    1.217401
3   1.048902    1.276934
4   1.068631    1.364571
```

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend iterating, but the fact that each sequential calculation depends on the result of the previous calculation complicates vectorization.

You would either use `apply`, which would in a way be looping over your rows, or you could explicitly loop over your rows and perform your calculation using `.loc`.

Consider the first 4 rows of your `DF`:

```
>>> df
      Index  Values
0  1.066373     1.0
1  1.126100     NaN
2  1.081077     NaN
3  1.048902     NaN
4  1.068631     NaN
```

---

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'Values'] = df.loc[i-1, 'Values'] * df.loc[i, 'Index']
```

Updates your Values column in your `DF` to:

```
      Index    Values
0  1.066373  1.000000
1  1.126100  1.126100
2  1.081077  1.217401
3  1.048902  1.276934
4  1.068631  1.364571
```

Some remarks:

1. Make sure that your 'Index' column, is a column and not your index.
2. `range(1,...)` makes sure your `loop` starts from `index` 1 and not 0.
3. I assume this will be slow if your `DF` is large

Comment: And if '1' is repeating more then 1 times, how to calculate?

Comment: You can adjust the ```range(1,)``` value depending on how many ```1's``` you have.

Comment: But this values is not only at begin. I.E. 1









1









1









1

Comment: When the cycle is 1 it starts again

Comment: Thank you so much. My Notebook get an Errors, but when i do it in pycharm it works:)

Comment: Happy to help @Dess!